# How do I disable thumbnails for TIF files only?

Tags: windows-7, thumbnails, tiff

The TIFF bug has been around for years: The system freezes for minutes when going near large (above 700 MB - 1 GB) TIFF files with layers and compression. Microsoft doesn't seem to be able to fix this for Windows 7 64 bit.

I would like to know if there is a possible workaround. Sure I could just disable the whole thumbnailing, but I don't want that. For the files it actually works with, it's very practical. So can I somehow exclude just the TIF files from the thumbnail creation process?

I have read [Huge TIFF file bogs down Explorer thumbnail generation](https://superuser.com/questions/23575/huge-tiff-file-bogs-down-explorer-thumbnail-generation) , but it does not work for me because I already don't have that ShellEx entry in my registry. I can't delete it an entry that doesn't exist. The other question is also about deactivating the thumbnails globally, which I don't want.

Comment: This is still a duplicate of the other question. It presents the same problem. Just because the answer to that question didn't work for you does not change that. Instead of opening multiple duplicates, do everything you can to support the original question.

Comment: Well i tried pointing out that that answer isnt working for me, but that got deleted too... That was the first thing i tried.

Comment: Again - that is what should happen. What you need to do is encourage new answers to the original question. You can do this by providing your own answer to add any new information you learn in researching this yourself, or by adding a bounty to the question if you can earn enough reputation here, both of which will bump that question back to the top of the active list.

Comment: Problem is, i dont have answers, just a question, wich it seems im not allowed to ask.

Comment: If you've already tried what's in the other answers, and it's not working for you, that's IMHO okay. What you shouldn't do however is post another question when [an older one's of yours was closed](http://superuser.com/questions/377644/how-to-disable-thumbnails-for-tif-files-only). Note that it's "closed", not "deleted" and can always be reopened. You should have explained why it's not a duplicate and `flagged` it for a moderator to have it reopened (since a moderator also closed it). And please, don't swear. Thanks.

Comment: I found additional information and another workaround. if any of this is usefull, it would be good if it was put WAY back in the original Q, if not then it can die here :-) http://www.modelmayhem.com/po.php?thread_id=616900 Does a deep analisis of the problem. Then points to a link http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-7-ultimate-64-lag-and-freezing-when/a473c4ca-3fe2-4b6d-847f-6287e4d24e81 <-- where there are other workarounds. "Optomise this folder for . . "  (so it doesnt make those thumbs?)   Does not work in library Piles, so organise better.

Comment: @anyone swearing gets you nowhere - if the dupe doesn't work out flag for mod attention  & mention why you want it renamed. And as slhck mentions, it was not deleted

Comment: I know i can disable it per folder, but there will always be new photoshoots, and always new folders where i would have to spend additional time in setting it up, and again this would also deacivate the preview for raw and jpgs. Its not really practical enough for me. The codec pack didnt change anything. Then i tried removing everything in the registry for .tif, even created an empty "ShellEx" key, but Windows is still previewing them.

Comment: @Sathya, well you are the mods, you decide what to do, removing my 2 new questions and allowing me to post in the old one, or just remove the closed on and keeep this going (and i will post the solution in the old one to if there is any). As long as you give me a chance to investigate this thing further im fine.

Comment: @anyone  I wonder if the Change via windows 7 for some issues is related to new features, like superfetch?  I never did like any aspect of the "file" systems previewing, because of how it slows things down generally.  So I always had previews off for the system, and a 3rd party picture browsing for browsing for pictures.  2 different thing for 2 different operations. Xp would not even thumb some files like targa , without an added hack.